# Does natural {peanut, cashew, almond} butter require refrigeration?

Tags: refrigerator, almonds, storage, peanuts, nut-butters

I have purchased a few different types of natural peanut butter and all have stated that refrigeration is required after opening. However, I recently purchased Archer's Farms Almond, Peanut & Cashew Butter from Target which doesn't say anything about refrigeration after opening. From what I've read on other sites (anecdotal) and some .edu sites, raw/natural nut butters can grow mold and do require refrigeration. Any ideas on why Archer's Farms butter doesn't say anything about refrigeration?

> ```
> Peanut butter
> unopened           6-9 months    Refrigeration not needed. Keeps
> opened             2-3 months    longer if refrigerated. Natural
>                                    peanut butter must be
>                                    refrigerated after opening.
> ```

http://www.ag.ndsu.edu/pubs/yf/foods/fn579-2.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think I've ever seen peanut butter grow mold, natural or commercial, refrigerated or not. What will happen with natural peanut butter is that the fat (of which there's plenty) will go rancid over time.

The oxidation process that leads to rancidity requires heat, light, and usually oxygen; keeping it in the refrigerator will therefore slow the process down significantly.

Manufacturers are probably not required to put the "keep refrigerated" warning on nut butters because eating rancid food technically won't kill you or make you seriously ill. When a product says to keep refrigerated, sometimes that's for safety, sometimes it's just for quality - in the case of peanut butter it's typically the latter.

Commercial peanut butter has a ton of sugar and other preservatives, which is why refrigeration is not necessary, even for quality purposes.

Comment: Commercial peanut butter *often* has a ton of sugar.... Most often, but you can buy can just ground up peanuts as peanut butter in the store.

Comment: My main concern here was natural/raw nut butter as it has no preservatives and sugar added. Still helpful info, though.

Comment: Maybe in USA? but in many parts of the world peanut butter is just ground peanuts, maybe some salt to taste, and maybe a little vegetable oil (often peanut) to help with less oily peanut varieties. Sugar in peanut butter....why?

Answer (score 2):

Call the company directly and ask. I do that with all my foods (I live without a refeigerator). I met people who never refrigerate mayonaisse and lived to tell. Turns out you don't need to if you don't introduce any other food particles into it! Now I never refrigerate mayo, or many other foods and condiments. So it pays to call the company and insist on the truth :-)

Comment: While I am glad this works for you please do not encourage others to not follow proper food storage procedures. What we do in our own kitchens is one thing but it is not a good idea to advise others that those practices are okay. That said, no company is going to advise a consumer not to follow proper procedures. In fact, most are overly conservative concerning food safety.

Answer (score 0):

I've never refrigerated my natural peanut or nut butters.   I eat it regularly so it does not sit around for long.  A quick stir before using.

Comment: How long is long? A week?

Comment: From what I've read, you can definitely leave natural peanut butter unrefrigerated for a month without it going rancid.  Still, always sniff before use.